# DateFormat from date get wrong date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

```
NSLog(@"Time From DB %@", mytime.beginTime);     
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
UILabel *timeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
timeLabel.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:mytime.beginTime];
NSLog(@"Time after formatting %@", timeLabel.text);
[timeFormatter release];
```

Console

```
2011-07-05 11:16:09.331 My project[1907:207] Time From DB 2011-05-10 13:54:09 +0000
2011-07-05 11:16:09.331 My project[1907:207] Time after formatting 04:54 PM
```

Why are the times different? How to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is using the user's time zone (default). If you want it in GMT, you will have to set the time zone of the date formatter.

```
[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

BTW Times aren't different. Time is the same but is being represented in different time zones.

Answer (score 2):

The date *2011-05-10 13:54:09 +0000* has the value in the **GMT** time zone, as you can notice this from **+0000** in the date. So, while converting, the date formatter uses the phone's time zone, that is your location's time zone, which is **-03:00**, it seems. So in order to convert a date in GMT time zone to a GMT time zone date, you need to explicitly set the time zone of the date formatter to GMT, if GMT is not the phone's default time zone, as specified in @Deepak's answer.